# How do I "select" wave out to be the line-in source in windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

In XP, I could open the recording panel from the tray and "select" the wave-out. then, in all applications (like Winamp) I could tune to the linein and capture/use that data (e.g. using Winamp's Milkdrop to visualize the audio coming from a website or other application)

I have no idea how to do this in Win 7.

Answer (score 0):

Try [JACK](http://jackaudio.org/):

> JACK is system for handling real-time, low latency audio (and MIDI).
>   It runs on GNU/Linux, Solaris, FreeBSD, OS X and Windows (and can be
>   ported to other POSIX-conformant platforms). It **can connect a number
>   of different applications to an audio device, as well as allowing them
>   to share audio between themselves.** Its clients can run in their own
>   processes (ie. as normal applications), or can they can run within the
>   JACK server (ie. as a "plugin"). JACK also has support for
>   distributing audio processing across a network, both fast & reliable
>   LANs as well as slower, less reliable WANs.

Comment: it sounded promising, but I couldn't get it working - they don't offer a ton of docs...

Comment: I had similar problems with it, still waiting on answers. There's another called Virtual Audio cable too, but it was problematic as well.

Comment: let me know if you get anything working!